# Update owl Carousel number of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel-2

I've added Owl carousel to a page. I want to update number of items after ajax call. I tried this but it's not working on my end.

```js
jQuery('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 4,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1,
      nav: true
    },
    640: {
      items: 2,
      nav: true
    },
    1025: {
      items: 4,
      nav: true
    }
  }
});

jQuery('.owl-carousel').trigger('initialize.owl.carousel');
jQuery('.owl-carousel').trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the impression that Owl Carousel has a function to detect and add slides. You can add and remove them manually, but not automatically.

You probably want to destroy and rebuild:

```
...trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');
...owlCarousel({...});
```

You could detect the current slide before rebuild and reapply it on rebuild, though it might not match depending on how the data have changed.

Protip: Save yourself some typing and use this shorthand with alias as your `document.ready` wrapper. Then you can use `$` instead of `jQuery` in your script statements.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // your script, e.g. 
    // $('.owl-carousel').trigger();
});
```